# Resetting vars to their original state

Tags: c#, class, variables, structure

Not sure on how one would explain this scenario, so I'm going to try my best whilst using examples..

So I have a main class,

```
Main.cs


//Code

class Main {
    public Run() {
        while(true)
        {
            Minor start = new Minor();
            start.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Minor class,

```
Minor.cs

//Code

class Minor {
    public Run() {
        Test.hi += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(Test.hi);
    }
}
```

Test class,

```
Test.cs

//Code

class Test {
    public int hi = 0;
}
```

Whilst running the above example, each loop the integer within Time.cs will increase.. So output would be, for 3 runs..

```
1
2
3
```

However if I were to place `public int hi = 0` inside, Minor.cs as shown below

```
Minor.cs

//Code

class Minor {

    public int hi = 0;

    public Run() {
        hi += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(Test.hi);
    }

}
```

The output would always be `1` due to the fact each loop a new instance of Minor is created... Now I know I could just simply create a new instance of `Test.cs` within `Minor.cs` but I have multiple variable/integers/strings that are modified during loop, however need to be default value on the next loop.

Is it possible to programmatically reset all classes to their default states programmatically other than `Main.cs` OR is it possible to inherit all other `classes` into `Minor.cs` so that when a new instance of `Minor.cs` is created, a new instance of those are too?

Comment: Welcome to SO Space Code. I am not sure I understand your question because the answer seems so obvious; if you want to reset a variable, such as `hi`, to 0, you simply write `hi = 0;`.  Or if you really want to be fancy I guess you could write `hi = default(int)` (which sets it to 0). Is there some aspect of the problem I am missing?

Comment: @JohnWu I was hoping their may be a way to reset all integers to default programmatically/simultaneously, similar to how you would create a new Instance of a class, ie `Class test = new Class();` but rather than do that for each class, there be one parent class and when a new instance of the parent class is made, it creates a new instance of every child class

Comment: I think you already know how, OP. You just need to organize your variables differently. Put the variables you want to be reset all in one class, and reinstantiate that one with each iteration; put variables you want to keep in a different class, and create that one only once.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your constraints, but if you want to reset all the variables in a class, I would think to add a `Reset()` method to that class, which just does that: sets all the properties to default one by one.

Comment: Yeah I had thought of that, but due to there being multiple classes, I would have to call `Class1.Reset();, Class2.Reset(); and so on`, where as I was hoping there could potentially be a way to create a parent class, that has child classes and when a new instance of that class is made `(which sets it to the classes original state)` so will the child classes. Reducing the call to one, rather than multiple.

Comment: You could pass one class (a "child") into the constructor of another (the "parent"), and program the "parent's" `Reset` method to also call `Reset` on the "child". How about that?

Comment: It could be done I guess,  thanks for your input & help towards a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself the solution is to create a new object of Test.

```
public Run() {
        var test = new Test():
        Console.WriteLine(Test.hi);// I'm assuming this should be  'test.hi'
    }
```